# Can I hide the green color of traffic layer in Google maps javascript api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working on Google maps javascript api v3. I need to view only the slow traffic area(red,orange roads) in traffic layer. Can I hide the green colored roads?

Can I change the green colored road to any other color or make it transparent?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API doesn't offer such an option ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=fr#TrafficLayerOptions)). And since Google delivers pre-rendered map tiles ([example](https://www.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i16!2i11241!3i26170!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i367042808!2m12!1e2!2spsm!4m2!1sgid!2sCHn_EYPY9eeHdaYoxXsZjQ!4m2!1ssp!2s1!5i1!8m2!13m1!14b1!2m6!1e2!2straffic!4m3!1st!2s2464333!5i1!3m20!2sfr!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e52!2m2!1sentity_class!2s0!12m5!1e14!2m1!1ssolid!2m1!1soffset_polylines!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&token=85820)) as *png*, they aren't editable.